# What is the rule for interning of strings are float values also interned?

Tags: python, string

```
a="ab d"
b="ab d"
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
```

sometimes it is getting interned, sometimes not. What is the general rule for interning of a string in version 3.9 of python.

and are float also get interned or not. I am getting different result every time for this too.

```
c=3.02
d=3.02
print(id(c))
print(id(d))
```

Comment: You should just not rely on a particular interning behavior.

Comment: Why do you care if a string is interned?  Unless you explicitly call sys.intern, you cannot make any assumptions about whether two strings that are == are also identical.

Comment: **There is no rule**. Any interning or caching that occurs of `str` and `float` objects are **implementation details that should never be relied on**